# single regex match with two words

Tags: regex

I'm sorry I have not big knowledge in using regular expressions. I've been asked to check if I can retreive with a **single** line regex 2 integer as a single output, so concatenated.

For instance, from the expression:

```
sip:+17036380464;rn=+15712652210;spid=6214;mcc=310;mnc=150;npdi@enode.net
```

I have to retreive the value

```
310150
```

as the first output

I was able to retreive the two values separately with

```
.*mcc=(([0-9]*);mnc=([0-9]*));.*
```

but I have no idea how to accomplish it into one output

Many thanks

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: I'll need to check. I'm just using a GUI in which I can modify the regular expression to apply. From there I cannot see any code, though I think it is based on javascript

Answer (score 2):

In perl:

```
$str = 'sip:+17036380464;rn=+15712652210;spid=6214;mcc=310;mnc=150;npdi@enode.net';
$str =~ s/^.*mcc=([0-9]*);mnc=([0-9]*).*$/$1$2/;
```

In php:

```
$str = 'sip:+17036380464;rn=+15712652210;spid=6214;mcc=310;mnc=150;npdi@enode.net';
$str = preg_replace('/^.*mcc=([0-9]*);mnc=([0-9]*).*$/', "$1$2", $str);
```

In JavaScript:

```
str = 'sip:+17036380464;rn=+15712652210;spid=6214;mcc=310;mnc=150;npdi@enode.net';
str.replace(/^.*mcc=([0-9]*);mnc=([0-9]*).*$/, "$1$2");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.mcc=([0-9]*);mnc=([0-9]*);
```

Then `$1` is the first part and `$2` is the second part, you just need to combine them.

Comment: thank you. the problem is that i have a code that only allows for a single line regex, not a script. which means that I have to retreive the concatenation of the two values into $1